# Editing after enter phone Number not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c

iOS- Using the below code i am able to add hyphen automatticaly but not able to do editing in the textfield properly:- Editing like when click to insert any number between the filled numbers this will edit at the end of the number And Further not delete that number properly. AnyOne can help me out IOS
Suppose the user first time enters the number like 123-456-7890. After that he want to change the digit 4 with 7 then the 7 digit is not inserted at the proper place. And the limit of 10 digit number would be exceed . i want to solve this problem. Give me the solution of the editing the code . Dont only erase the spaces in the code and show me again

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
   {    
      if(textField == txtUserName)
       {
            if (range.location == 12)
           {
              return NO;
             }
          if (range.length == 0 && ![[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]   characterIsMember:[string characterAtIndex:0]])
            {
             return NO;
             }       
        if (range.length == 0 && (range.location == 3 || range.location == 7))
           {
              txtUserName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-  %@",txtUserName.text,string];
              return NO;
             }
          if (range.length == 1 &&(range.location==4 ||range.location ==7))      
           {
               range.location--;
               range.length = 2;
                txtUserName.text = [txtUserName.text  stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
              NSLog(@"Nisha..%@",txtUserName.text);
               return NO;
            }
          }     
         return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove space in

```
txtNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",txtNumber.text,string];
```

Because space is also count as a character.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
     if(textField == txtNumber)
     {
        if (range.location == 12)
        {
            return NO;
        }
        if (range.length == 0 && ![[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]   characterIsMember:[string characterAtIndex:0]])
        {
            return NO;
        }
        if (range.length == 0 && (range.location == 3 || range.location == 7))
        {
            txtNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",txtNumber.text,string];
            return NO;
        }
        if (range.length == 1 &&(range.location==4 ||range.location ==7))
        {
            range.location--;
            range.length = 2;
            txtNumber.text = [txtNumber.text  stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
            NSLog(@"Nisha..%@",txtNumber.text);
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: fail code...have two bugs are you proper test your code @Mohak

Comment: @Mohak.. My question is i am not able to do editing in textfield propely. Otherwise the code will work proper. There is not any space issue.